# React - getting inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react form with two inputs:

```
<input type="name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="description" className="form-control" placeholder="Description"/>
```

Because the types of the input fields are `name` and `description` respectively,
I assumed that on form submission the fields `this.state.name` and `this.state.description` will be updated.

However, when I submit the form, these fields do not change their values.

The full code for the form is:

```
<form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
                 </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input type="description" className="form-control" placeholder="Description"/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

How can I get the values filled in by the user?

Comment: There are several ways how you can get values from form, one of them use refs like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/18494/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways how you can get values from form, one of them you can use `refs` like this

```
<input ref="name" type="name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
<input ref="description" type="description" className="form-control" placeholder="Description"/>

var name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.name).value,
    description = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.description).value;
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/18494/)

**Note** Example for `React` version `>= 0.14` where there is `react-dom`. For version `<= 0.13` instead of `ReactDOM` use `React`

Also you can use `states` like this

```
<input onChange={this.updateName} type="name" className="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
<input onChange={this.updateDescription} type="description" className="form-control" placeholder="Description"/>

handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = this.state.name;
        description = this.state.description;
},

getInitialState: function () {
    return { name: '', description: '' };
},

updateName: function (e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });    
}, 

updateDescription: function (e) {
    this.setState({ description: e.target.value });
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/18498/)

Answer (score 2):

You should do as the original documentation says here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

I have modified the code sample in the docs to suit your case. I know this could be done more dynamic but I have done it like this for the sake of simplicity.

```
      getInitialState: function() {
         return {
            valueName: 'Name', 
            valueDesc: 'Description'
         };
      },
      // here you handle all the changes in the input
      handleNameChange: function(event) {
         this.setState({valueName: event.target.value});
      },
      handleDescChange: function(event) {
         this.setState({valueDesc: event.target.value});
      },
      render: function() {
         return (<div>
                    <input type="name" value={this.state.valueName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="description" value={this.state.valueDesc} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>);
      }
```